# Separate number with commas after 3 digits white managing decimal places on a string iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, number-formatting, nsnumberformatter

I have following variables

```
NSString* balance = @"43243534.4535345"
int decimalPoint = 2;
```

How can we place commas after three digits while managing decimal point according to given variable at same time.
It's easy to do these action separately but how can we perform them together so result should be:  43,243,534.45

Comment: Your question is tagged `NSNumberFormatter`. Please update your question with what you have attempted. Explain what problem you are having getting the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSNumberFormatter`:

```
double number = 43243534.4535345;
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2;
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
NSString *numberString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@(number)];
NSLog(@"%@", numberString); 
//43,243,534.45 in log
```

in Swift:

```
let number = 43243534.4535345
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
let formattedString = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: number))
```

Comment: Why did you set `minimumFractionDigits` to `7` when the OP wants 2 decimal places. Why are you setting the `decimalSeparator` to `,` when the OP is showing a `.` for the decimal separator. Why set the `decimalSeparator` at all? Let the number be formatted properly for the user's locale.

Comment: You want both `minimumFractionDigits` and `maximumFractionDigits`. Without `minimumFractionDigits`, you'll get `0.5` rather than `0.50`. Without `maximumFractionDigits`, you'll get `0.6666` rather than `0.67`.